# How to return multiple results by searching keywords in python Youtube_dl

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, discord.py, youtube-dl

So, I want to search by keywords using `youtube_dl`. I know that I could search multiple results by adding number after "ytsearch" in my `extract_info` function. 
For example `ytsearch5` for 5 results. Then in the console, it says downloading 5 webpages but it only returns the info dictionary of the first result. My partial code is below

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

ydl_option = {'format': 'bestaudio'}

query = input() # user input the keywords query
with YoutubeDL(ydl_option) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch5{query}", download=False)

print(info) # this will only give me dictionary of first results, though downloading 5 results webpages.
```

So, could anyone help me with this please? Any suggestion is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: I'd say it returns only the dictionary of the last result, well, you are overwriting `info` with each iteration, you, perhaps, wanted to place the `print` function in the for loop (i.e. indent one level to the right)

Comment: it will still return only one result, and it is the first result based on the first webpage it downloaded.